# Drop a colum from very large table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have used the following query to  drop a column in a table[having more than 2 laks records]

```
Alter table Table Name Drop column column name
```

But it takes more time. I can't predict time .it's too time consuming more 2 hours to drop a column.

Can you please suggest How to Drop a column in vary large table with efficient way?

Comment: That does the same exact thing

Answer (score 3):

DROP COLUMN is almost always nearly instantaneous, as is not a size-of-data operation.

the DDL does not complete because you are **blocked**. DDL, like ALTER TABLE, requires SCH-M access to the table and will have to wait until all pending operations release any conflicting lock (and any other locks is conflicting with SCH-M) on the table. Use [Activity Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212951.aspx) to determine what is blocking you. Take appropriate action depending on what you discover.